# Share HTML Content in Windows Phone 8.1 C# WinRT (Share Contract)

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1

I have the html code which I need to share. When I run the below code on Windows Desktop/laptop (Winrt) it shows up the data and image in outlook or gmail app but same code when I try to share on Windows Phone 8.1 it just shows the title but not the html content.

```
DataTransferManager manager = null;

protected override void OnNavigatedFrom(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    manager = DataTransferManager.GetForCurrentView();
    manager.DataRequested += new TypedEventHandler<DataTransferManager, DataRequestedEventArgs>(share_DataRequested);
}

private void share_DataRequested(object sender, DataRequestedEventArgs e)
{
    DataRequestDeferral deferral = e.Request.GetDeferral();

    DataRequest request = e.Request;
    request.Data.Properties.Title = "This is my Title";
    request.Data.Properties.ApplicationName = "App Name";

    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

    builder.Append("<img src='URI_Image' title='something' /> ");       
    builder.Append("<pre style='font-family:Helvetica'>some data</pre>");

    request.Data.SetHtmlFormat(HtmlFormatHelper.CreateHtmlFormat(builder.ToString()));

    deferral.Complete();

}

private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    DataTransferManager.ShowShareUI();
}
```

[Demo App Download Link](http://1drv.ms/1T7rFc8)

How can I resolve this..

Comment: Have you tried constructing a valid HTML Document?

Comment: constructing in the sense like ?

Comment: Yes Rowlond I have tried but no use..

Answer (score 0):

try to change your code to :

```
var builder = new StringBuilder();
builder.Append(@"<!DOCTYPE html>");       
builder.Append(@"<html itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/QAPage">");
builder.Append(@"<head>");
builder.Append(@"<title>My web page</title>");
builder.Append(@"</head>");
builder.Append(@"<body>");
builder.Append(@"<img src="URI_Image" title="something" /> ");       
builder.Append(@"<pre style="font-family:Helvetica">some data</pre>");
builder.Append(@"</head>");
builder.Append(@"</body>");
builder.Append(@"</html>");
```

Comment: Hello danvy, I tried your code but same output.
What ever I share it, it doesn't appear it just shows a blank but only title appears.

I have done a sample app can you please check it out.
http://1drv.ms/1T7rFc8